# How to get CPU temperature on Windows system using both Snmp and cmd

Tags: windows, cpu, temperature, snmp, zabbix

I am currently working on NMS Zabbix. After some R&D, I am able to get the CPU temperature info on Linux via snmp as well as terminal using LM-SENSORS. However, the same doesn't work for Windows; I see windows doesn't have LM-SENSORS, and maybe that's why LM-SENSOR-MIB is not giving any output for Windows. Can any one suggest which mibs can be used in Windows to get CPU temperature info, and also, how can I get same information in a cmd terminal?

Answer (score 12):

#### How can I get the CPU temperature in a cmd shell?

Try the following.

**Batch file (GetCpuTmp.cmd)**

> ```
> @echo off
> for /f "skip=1 tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi PATH MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature get CurrentTemperature /value') do set /a "HunDegCel=(%%~A*10)-27315"
> echo %HunDegCel:~0,-2%.%HunDegCel:~-2% Degrees Celsius
> ```

Source [Batch-file get CPU temperature in °C and set as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24005062/3536342), answer by [David Ruhmann](http://david%20ruhmann/)

Example output:

```
> GetCpuTemp.cmd
73.05 Degrees Celsius
```

---

**PowerShell function (get-temperature.psm1)**

```
function Get-Temperature {
    $t = Get-WmiObject MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature -Namespace "root/wmi"

    $currentTempKelvin = $t.CurrentTemperature / 10
    $currentTempCelsius = $currentTempKelvin - 273.15

    $currentTempFahrenheit = (9/5) * $currentTempCelsius + 32

    return $currentTempCelsius.ToString() + " C : " + $currentTempFahrenheit.ToString() + " F : " + $currentTempKelvin + "K"  
}

# Save in your c:\users\yourName\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\modules\ directory
# in sub directory get-temperature as get-temperature.psm1
# You **must** run as Administrator.
# It will only work if your system & BIOS support it. If it doesn't work, I can't help you.

# Just type get-temperature in PowerShell and it will spit back the temp in Celsius, Farenheit and Kelvin.
```

Source [Get CPU Temperature With PowerShell](https://gist.github.com/jeffa00/9577816)

Example output:

```
> get-temperature
73.05 C : 163.49 F : 346.2K
```

Comment: thankyou I tried but it didn't work, I tried searching for some 3rd party application which can give me cmd output but I couldn't find any, do you have any idea about any app that can give temperature output in txt file or command prompt. I tried installing coretemp, realtemp, HWMonitor but all of them are GUI based and don't give output at terminal level or in txt file.

Comment: Did you run the scripts as administrator?

Comment: >Yes , here is my cmd output

>C:\paras> GetCpuTmp.cmd

>Node - PUNSHI-WINDOWS

>ERROR:

>Description = Not supported

>~0,-2HunDegCel:~-2 Degrees Celsius

Comment: This is not CPU temp, but rather mb temp https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101295/msacpi-thermalzonetemperature-class-not-showing-actual-temperature/17083409#17083409

Comment: To run this you need to run the command here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4038991  However, as stated in the comment above, it does not give you the CPU temperature.

Comment: `Get-WmiObject` has since this answer been superseded by `Get-CimInstance`, see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject?view=powershell-5.1#description). The return object is an array of thermal zones; see the comments in the source-link above for a fix.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Open Hardware Monitor it's an open source software (MPL v2). 
You can access the command line version here:

[OpenHardwareMonitorReport.zip](https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor/openhardwaremonitor/files/1130239/OpenHardwareMonitorReport.zip)

Example part of the output:

```
PS C:\Users\myuser\OpenHardwareMonitorReport> .\OpenHardwareMonitorReport.exe

Open Hardware Monitor Report

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Version: 0.8.0.2

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Common Language Runtime: 4.0.30319.42000
Operating System: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
Process Type: 32-Bit

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Sensors

|
+- HP 00F52W (/mainboard)
|
+- Intel Core i7-3770 (/intelcpu/0)
|  +- Bus Speed      :  99.7734  99.7734  99.7784 (/intelcpu/0/clock/0)
|  +- CPU Core #1    :  3691.62  3691.62  3791.58 (/intelcpu/0/clock/1)
|  +- CPU Core #2    :  3691.62  3691.62  3791.58 (/intelcpu/0/clock/2)
|  +- CPU Core #3    :  3791.39  3791.39  3891.36 (/intelcpu/0/clock/3)
|  +- CPU Core #4    :  3691.62  3691.62  3891.36 (/intelcpu/0/clock/4)
|  +- CPU Core #1    :       42       42       43 (/intelcpu/0/temperature/0)
|  +- CPU Core #2    :       43       37       43 (/intelcpu/0/temperature/1)
|  +- CPU Core #3    :       42       35       42 (/intelcpu/0/temperature/2)
|  +- CPU Core #4    :       45       41       45 (/intelcpu/0/temperature/3)
|  +- CPU Package    :       45       43       45 (/intelcpu/0/temperature/4)
```

- [Open Hardware Monitor Official website](https://openhardwaremonitor.org/)
- link to issue where the command line version is
  linked: [#776](https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor/openhardwaremonitor/issues/776#issuecomment-313606249)
- More recent version with pending [pull request](https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor/openhardwaremonitor/pull/1115#issuecomment-616230088)

Comment: OpenHardwareMonitor doesn't work properly on my PC. No temperatures are shown. The only other program I have found is HWiNFO64 Pro which isn't free. Is there really no other software?

Comment: @Aenfa did you check the recent version https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor/openhardwaremonitor/pull/1115#issuecomment-1189362017

Comment: Still no temperature information when trying the recent version.

Comment: @Aenfa found this fork of the application with more recent updates
https://github.com/hexagon-oss/openhardwaremonitor

Comment: Also found this @Aenfa
https://github.com/LibreHardwareMonitor/LibreHardwareMonitor

Comment: LibreHardwareMonitor works but how can I use it from the command line?

Comment: Aenfa, not sure if it supports CMD, if no please open an issue in LibreHardwareMonitor github and mention the PR that offered to add it to the original software.